# Beamer numbering problem, I only use one section, but I want to add section number without section command

Tags: beamer, numbering, number

I want to add 2. in front of every numbering like equations, lists, and figures.
Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

One way is change the `\theequation` accordingly:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand\theequation{2.\arabic{equation}}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Numbered equations}

    \begin{equation}
 y=f(x)=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\, \mathrm{d}x
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the `amsmath` documentation section 3.11:
"if you wanted to have equations numbered within sections -[...]- you could redefine `\theequation` as suggested in the LATEX manual:"

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
```

If you just want a 2, put that instead of `\thesection`

As for tables, you should be able to do something similar with `\thetable` instead of `\theequation`. Anyway, check this out to better understand how it all works: [Counters - Overleaf documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Counters)

Hope this answers. Cheers!